# Prove that there exists a $c$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(c)=g(c)$

Tags: functions, continuity

There is this problem with an exercise in my maths book, it's included in the chapter on continuity.

> Consider two functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, with the property that there exist $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ so that $f(a)=g(b)$ and $f(b)=g(a)$. 
>   Prove that there exists a $c$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(c)=g(c)$

Also, I've considered another function $h$ and I have come at the end to $h(a)=h(b)$, then two cases arose: $a=b$ or $a\neq b$.

For the first case I did prove that the $c$ exists, but for the second one I couldn't think of anything.

How could you use continuity (and maybe intermediate values)  in this problem?

Comment: I don't know if whereas is the correct word to use, i'd be happy if anyone can correct if i'm wrong.

Comment: "Such that" probably, but whereas isn't bad.

Comment: Assume $f(a) \geq g(a)$ by symmetry. Let $h(x) = f(x)-g(x)$ the result follows immediately using Intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ and then 
$$h(a)=f(a)-g(a)=g(b)-f(b)=-(f(b)-g(b))=-h(b)$$

1. if $\color{blue}{h(a) >0}$ (or $\color{green}{h(a) <0}$) then $\color{blue}{h(b) <0}$ (or $\color{green}{h(b)>0}$) and by [Bolzano's Theorem](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/ivt.shtml) $\exists c \in [a,b]$ such that $h(c)=0$ and $f(c)=g(c)$ as a result.
2. if $h(a)=0$ then $h(b)=0$ then we are done (i.e. $c=a$ or $c=b$).

Comment: Thanks everyone so much this is absolutely helpful.